# A question about hearing abuse of saintly persons?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, bhakti

I read somewhere in bhagavatam probably that if a ksatriya hears abuse of saintly persons then he should kill the abuser and commit suicide and if brahmana hears abuse then he should go away from there and plunge himself in water(die)..
Can you quote(find) the verse and any other verse in other scriptures about this topic?
Thanks